# Как получить в цикле значение элементов добавленных через jQuery?

Tags: jquery, битрикс, click

Пытаюсь победить календарь от дяди Битрикса.
У него в коде каждый день имеет дата-аттрибут. Мне нужно считывать эти аттрибуты для дальнейшей обработки.
Дело в том,что при переключений с текущего месяца на следующий или предыдущий блок с днями обновляется, и найти эти добавленные элементы не получается.

Пробовал код (клик по кнопочке, которая переключает на предыдущий месяц)

```
$('body').on('click', '.bx-calendar-left-arrow' , function() {
///код сравнения дата аттрибутов с константой});
});
```

не находит. Скорее всего, после нажатия на кнопочку смены месяца идет подгрузка, таймер что ли ставить??? Не хотелось бы...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверняка есть метод (или даже коллбэк), которрый вызывается после формирования нового месяца. Нужно в исходниках накопать

Comment: там один коллбэк)) после выбора даты.. https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/js_lib/data/calendar.php